# Verifying multiple string match from range of cells

Tags: google-sheets

I am using google sheets. My sheet is for scheduling students. There are multiple teachers that teach a subject each hour, and I want to validate a student's schedule by ensuring they have each of the four required classes preset. Math, ELA, Science, and Social Studies. As the example below shows, the scheduler chooses from a drop down list of available classes for each hour. The cell contains the teacher's name and the subject taught. The Validation cell should search across the row for each of the four partial strings "ELA", "Math", "Science", "Social Stud" and return "Good" if all four are present, or "Error" if there is a duplicate, or one missing. Any ideas?

[image: Google sheet image]

Comment: What is your formula so far?

Comment: @ Liora Haydont
 I've tried  a few different approaches.
Nested If's
=if(countif(A3:F3,"*ELA")=1, if(countif(A3:F3,"*Math")=1,if(countif(A3:F3,"*Social")=1,if(countif(A3:F3,"*Science")=1,"false"))))

Before I needed to add the subject in addition to the teacher name, I had a list of teachers in Roster!Roster!G$32:G$35
=If(A6="","",If(CONCATENATE(Sort(Transpose(C6:F6)))=CONCATENATE(Sort(Roster!G$32:G$35)),"Good","Missing"))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply use `AND` in a `IF` condition

```
=if(
   AND(
      countif(A3:F3,"*ELA")=1,
      countif(A3:F3,"*Math")=1, 
      countif(A3:F3,"*Social")=1,
      countif(A3:F3,"*Science")=1,
   ),
   "Good",
   "Error")
```

if you have other validation you can add it to the `AND` or even add a `AND/OR` confition inside a condition

Comment: That worked great. Made a few changes. Ensured it only validates if there is a name in the "Student" column, I changed the verified range to C3:F3, and added an extra wildcard to countif(A3:F3,"*Social")=1 although, I could also have just changed it to "Social Studies".  Final formula is `=if(A3="","",if(
   AND(
      countif(C3:F3,"*ELA")=1,
      countif(C3:F3,"*Math")=1, 
      countif(C3:F3,"*Social*")=1,
      countif(C3:F3,"*Science")=1,
   ),
   "Good",
   "Error") 
)`

Answer (score 1):

If there is any chance you might change your strings (Math, ELA, etc), I would recommend declaring them as named ranges, and then you wouldn't have to change all the formulas if you change your strings.

I created an example sheet here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1P9VjIWLQBm9D75caNI1GH4US9buubPj7LpKFe8vLw2M/edit?usp=sharing

Here's the formula I used (though it performs the same basic function as your accepted answer without requiring wildcards):

```
=if(isnumber(sum(SEARCH(string1,join(" ",B2:E2)),SEARCH(string2,join(" ",B2:E2)),SEARCH(string3,join(" ",B2:E2)),SEARCH(string4,join(" ",B2:E2)))),Good,Bad)
```

I'm using named ranges for the valid or error responses as well ("Good" & "Bad"). Again, named ranges allow you to change the string on your "Variables" sheet without having to alter the formulas in your Validation cells